# text in variable will be indentified but wont be displayed

Tags: php, mysql, html, variables

i have some strange phenomenon. i have a variable in that is some text:

```
rename something;
mkdir a folder;
$msg = "this text should be displayed";
$mail to...
```

in the html i have:

```
<?php if (!isset($msg)):?>
some inputfileds
<?php endif; ?>
```

the phenomenon is that everything works fine except `$msg` that wont be displayed. the curious about that is, that it has worked before on another page. the variable will be identified as it because the inputfields will be hidden after pressing submit and `$errors == 0`. there is also working the rename function, mkdir, and the mail. if i change `$msg =` into `echo` it will echo out the message how it should do. so i really have no clue whats might be wrong to this?

if there is someone who could tell what to do to solve this i really would appreciate. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if I understood your query correctly but if you want to display the value of $msg in the html then you will have to put it in your html something like

```
<?php if (isset($msg)):?>
  <p><?php echo $msg; ?></p>
  <!-- some inputfileds -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: OMG... it was in the code but it was folded that i hasnt seen it. thanks alot.

Comment: hu? if NOT isset $msg => echo $msg? that makes not sense..how did this answer get an upvote?

Comment: sure, this answer makes no sense but it solved my problem. i had to look for some folded codebox in that the main goal -> echo $msg was hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to write it this way?

```
<?php echo(isset($msg))?$msg:""; ?>
```

Comment: hu? if NOT isset $msg => echo $msg? that makes not sense..how did this answer get an upvote?